# How to asymmetrical video side by side?

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc

I want asymmetrical side by side video with resolution 1920x1080. The first video has bitrate 1mb/s and the second video has bitrate 500kb/s. Both videos have the same resolution 1920x1080 and encoded h.265, container mp4.
I used ffmpeg code:

```
 ffmpeg -i leftvideo.mp4 -i rightvideo.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] scale=iw/2:ih, pad=2*iw:ih [left]; [1:v] scale=iw/2:ih [right]; [left][right] overlay=main_w/2:0 [out]" -map [out] -c:v libx265 output.mp4
```

It works well but I want the resulting video quality while keeping. I don't want re-encoded.

Is it possible the two videos change resolution (960x1080) and together packed into container mp4?

EDIT: or another method?

Answer (score 3):

## Using `ffmpeg`

You are required to re-encode if you want to use filters in `ffmpeg`, but if you want to "keep the quality" you can use a lossless output:

```
ffmpeg -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=iw/2:ih[l];[1:v]scale=iw/2:ih[r];[l][r]hstack" \
-c:v libx264 -qp 0 output.mp4
```

The resulting file size may be huge. If this is not acceptable you can try a "visually lossless" output by changing `-qp 0` to `-crf 18`.

You did not provide full details about your inputs, and did not mention audio, so I assumed you are not concerned with the audio.

You did not provide the complete console output from your command so I assumed your `ffmpeg` is new enough to use the hstack filter.

## Using `ffplay`

Another option is to just use your player to play side-by-side and not even deal with re-encoding. Example using `ffplay`.

```
ffplay -f lavfi "movie=left.mp4,scale=iw/2:ih[v0];movie=right.mp4,scale=iw/2:ih[v1];[v0][v1]hstack"
```

Comment: I don't use sound.

Comment: I tried to use lossless but output too big.

How do to choose the bitrate quality is the same  and size small?

Comment: When you use the videos in half resolution so should also be reduced to half the bit rate. So you can do bitrate = 750 kb/s
Is it correct?

Comment: @medic911 It is technically not possible to achieve the "same quality" if you're encoding with a lossy encoder; you can only provide enough bits that it looks good enough. I can't provide a specific value because quality is subjective. You'll just have to experiment to see what is acceptable for you with your specific inputs.

Comment: Using `ffplay` is just perfect! It'd be nice if `ffplay` had a way to show part of the video in the way `vivict` does: https://github.com/vivictorg/vivict